# Is there a way to perform multivariate glm in R (Multiple DV and Multiple IV)?

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I am fairly new to R and I want to do multivariate and univariate analysis of my dataset

Dataset example:
[image]

I have 32 dependent variables and 4 Independent variables all arranged in columns. I want to do multivariate analysis that tells me which of the independent variables is significantly impacting my proteins. Then I want to do univariate analysis on each protein to see which IV is significant for each protein.  I want this to be similar to multivariate analysis in SPSS something like:

```
model <- glm(df[,c(9:40]~df[,c(4:8)], family="poisson", data=df)
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

This is what I want to do for the univariate analysis

```
model_univariate <- glm(Protein1 ~ age + bmi+ gender+ group, family="poisson", data=data)
```

I  tried to do a for loop to try so I didn't have to input the formula one by one for each protein but I keep getting an error

```
IV <- df[,c(4:8)]

DV <-df[,c(9:40)]

for (y in DV){
form <- formula(paste(y, "~", IV))
models[[y]] <- glm(form, data = df, family="poisson") 
}
```

error message: Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
invalid term in model formula

Comment: The [`mcglm` package](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v084i04) fits multivariate glms in R. You can also fit bayesian multivariate repsonse models using [`rstanarm`](https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/stan_mvmer.html). `rstanarm` uses `stan` under the hood. The [`stan` manual](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_26/stan-users-guide/multivariate-outcomes.html) has additional information on bayesian multivariate response models in stan.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide an exampled dataset in the future. Let's say we have something like this:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rpois(4000,20),100,40))
colnames(df)[1:4] = c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
colnames(df)[5:8] = paste0("IV",1:4)
colnames(df)[9:40] = paste0("Protein",1:32)
```

Define DV and IV:

```
DV = colnames(df)[9:40]
IV = colnames(df)[5:8]
```

You have not defined multivariate response properly. If the intention is to fit all the responses at one go, but keep each response separate, the multi-response model you have only works for `lm`, not for `glm` which you need for the poisson.

If you want to to model all the responses, considering the relationship between them, the packages suggested by @eipi10 is indeed the way to go.

Univariate:

```
models = vector("list",length(DV))
names(models) = DV

for (y in DV){
form <- reformulate(response=y,IV)
models[[y]] <- glm(form, data = df, family="poisson") 
}

models[["Protein1"]]

Call:  glm(formula = form, family = "poisson", data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          IV1          IV2          IV3          IV4  
  3.3793743   -0.0063736   -0.0094023   -0.0026646   -0.0007955  

Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  95 Residual
Null Deviance:      123.4 
Residual Deviance: 118.4    AIC: 609.6
```